# Getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, when running the following query?

Tags: oracle11g, spatial

Any idea what is wrong with my query below? I checked many times, all parenthesis are matched.

```
SELECT filtered.geom
FROM
  (SELECT *
  FROM buildings b
  WHERE sdo_FILTER(b.geom, sdo_geometry( 2003, NULL, NULL, sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,3), sdo_ordinate_array( 50,50, 400, 400) ) ) = 'TRUE'
  ) AS filtered
WHERE sdo_NN( filtered, sdo_geometry(2001, NULL, sdo_point_type(200,200,NULL),NULL,NULL), 'sdo_num_res=1') = 'TRUE';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me there are 2 errors in the query. It should look like this:

```
  SELECT filtered.geom FROM (select * from buildings b
    where sdo_FILTER(b.geom, sdo_geometry( 2003, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,3), sdo_ordinate_array( 50,50, 400, 400) ) ) = 'TRUE') filtered
  WHERE sdo_NN( filtered.geom, sdo_geometry(2001, null, sdo_point_type(200,200,null),null,null), 'sdo_num_res=1') = 'TRUE';
```

Remove keyword "as" when naming alias and add geom on alias name in sdo_NN.